# Does mismatching of ns1 and tem in a SOAP Request affect the request?

Tags: php, xml, soap, soap-client

I don't know how to put this, but I was supposed to send a SOAP request with following format:

```xml
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
       <tem:RequestTopup>
           <tem:sClientUserName>?</tem:sClientUserName>
           <tem:sClientPassword>?</tem:sClientPassword>
           <tem:sClientTxID>?</tem:sClientTxID>
           <tem:sProductID>?</tem:sProductID>
           <tem:dProductPrice>?</tem:dProductPrice>
           <tem:sCustomerAccountNumber>?</tem:sCustomerAccountNumber>
           <tem:sCustomerMobileNumber>?</tem:sCustomerMobileNumber>
           <tem:sEncKey>?</tem:sEncKey>
      </tem:RequestTopup>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

My php code was like below:

```
$opts = array(
    'ssl' => array('ciphers' => 'RC4-SHA', 'verify_peer' => false, 'verify_peer_name' => false)
);

$params = array(
    'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
    'verifypeer' => false,
    'verifyhost' => false,
    'trace' => 1, 'exceptions' => 1,
    "connection_timeout" => 180,
    'stream_context' => stream_context_create($opts)
);



$client = new SoapClient("http://xmpl/connect.asmx?WSDL", $params);    

    $txn_id = "2017021234567";

$result = $client->RequestTopup(
    array(
        'sClientUserName' => '60123456789',
        'sClientPassword' => '123456789',
        'sProductID' => '1',
        'dProductPrice' => '10',
        'sClientTxID' => $txn_id,
        'sCustomerAccountNumber' => '60166527234',
        'sCustomerMobileNumber' => '60166527234',
        'sEncKey' => 'sample_enc',
    )
);

echo $client->__getLastRequest();
```

Now, the problem is this generates the xml in correct format alright, but replaces all the **"tem"** with **"ns1"**. I'm sorry to say this, but I do not even know the difference between the two and googling didn't help much.

Will this make any difference if I request the xml with "ns1" ? Or should I change it to "tem" as the client end expects it ? Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should not. Namespace prefixes only reference the actual namespace (The value in the `xmlns:*` namespace definition node). Prefixes are optional for element nodes and can change on each element node. So `tem:RequestTopup` should be actually read as `{http://tempuri.org/}RequestTopup`. Here are 3 examples that all resolve to a node in the namespace `http://tempuri.org/` with the local name `RequestTopup`

- `<tem:RequestTopup xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/"/>`
- `<ns1:RequestTopup xmlns:ns1="http://tempuri.org/"/>`
- `<RequestTopup xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"/>`

However, I have seen a lot more faulty implementations then I would like. They often rely on specific namespace prefixes and ignore the actual namespace.

Comment: thanks a lot.. you made everything clear.. is there any way however, to replace those ns1 with tem ?

Comment: You will have to recreate the XML nodes. I implemented an optimizer into FluentDOM that can be used to do this: https://github.com/FluentDOM/FluentDOM/blob/master/examples/Transformer/Namespaces/optimize.php